# Improve javascript code for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code has two drop down menus which load container on button click and drop down closes on clicking anywhere on page. Though the window load works but the pages inside takes too much time to load even on local server obviously because my javascript code isn't the way it should. So guys what should my javascript code like so that it loads page correctly and at the same time closes drop down on clicking anywhere on page [if both drop downs are open both should close on click like in snippet].

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction2(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  $("#notificationContainer").load("notifications.php");
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
  $("#scoreContainer").load("score.php");
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
.dropdown,
.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: 0;
}
.dropdown-content a,
.dropdown-content2 a {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.dropbtn {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  background: red;
}
.dropbtn2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  background: green;
}
.dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content2 {
  border: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
  border-top: none;
}
#notificationContainer,
#scoreContainer {
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right:15px;">
      <a href="home.php" class="hombtn"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:15px;">
      <div class="dropdown2">
        <button onclick="myFunction2(event)" class="dropbtn2">one</button>
        <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
          <div id="scoreContainer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:15px;">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn">two</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <div id="notificationContainer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above javascript is modified from the below single drop down menu code which loaded the page inside container instantly, but my modified version [above] takes too much time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
$( "#notificationContainer" ).load( "notifications.php" );
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: load your script tag bottom i.e before body which can give performance boost

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing inherently wrong or slow about your javascript code. have you tried inspecting how long your PHP code runs? because that's where I would start looking for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your dropdowns. They work fine. But they lack in design and the code looks way too much for such small control. I suggest you use *Bootstrap*. CSS and Javascript codes are external and you just need to place your dropdown in your project by coding some HTML.

There are several different designs and the way it works simpler than what you coded. Take a look at the below example and [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/) for more info about it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Dropdown Example</h2>
  <p>Nice design, easy usage, good performance.</p>
  <p><b>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</b></p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">THIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">IS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A DROPDOWN</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```